# Launching browser (Chromium or Firefox) without x server / xorg

Tags: pi-4, raspberry-pi-os, chromium, xorg, firefox

I need to launch Chromium (or alternatively Firefox) on a raspberry PI 4 8 GB running Raspberry OS 2021-05-07 without launching xorg / xserver. Is that feasible, for example by launching it in framebuffer mode?

Thank you all.

Comment: why do you need to run the browser that way?

Comment: Because I am developing an application that need to be run from within the browser and use as little amount of resources as possible. I am currently using the browser in kiosk mode, but it is an overkill. I think the question is really well researched since I can use other apps in framebuffer mode (such as vlc).

Comment: it appears to be a Linux question, not a Raspberry Pi question ... unless the RPi has some FB quirk specific to RPi

Comment: Ports of browsers (not the two above) specific to Linux and framebuffer enabled exist, so I would say it is specific to Raspberry.

Comment: `Ports of browsers (not the two above) specific to Linux and framebuffer enabled exist` - that would be where you should start looking then

Comment: Of course, but I would not have opened the question if I had found a solution by looking at them.

Comment: Using Wayland might not be what you're after but technically doesn't involve X: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=342600

Answer (score 0):

I think https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22757/how-to-run-an-app-in-a-framebuffer/22759 answers this well.

Framebuffer is a lot more basic than X protocol support, so the application has to be specially written to support it.

You'll need to use one of the browsers that has such a specialist port, not a general web-browser like Chromium or Firefox.